# Is there a way to update the Date Accessed or Date Modified value of a file without opening the file?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-8.1

I want to update the date modified or date accessed property of a file to keep track of when the file was last accessed.

In accessing the file I do not need to open it so I would like to avoid that if possible.

I have tried using `SavePropertiesAsync` for these properties but they are read-only. I would like to use something similar to `System.File.IO.SetLastWriteTime`/`SetLastAccessTime` but these functions are not available for Windows 8 apps.

Comment: Have you tried `SavePropertiesAsync` using `KeyValuePair`s? Based on [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.fileproperties.storageitemcontentproperties.aspx) it seems that you may have to set it via the `System.DateAccessed` key.